# serializer.save() causes creation_counter error

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

I followed the Rest-Framework Tutorial and set up my api as described with a serializer model. The `serializer.is_valid()` method returns true and when printing serializer.data and serializer.object it look as it should.

But when i call `serializer.save()` i get the following error message:

> 'str' object has no attribute 'creation_counter'

Does anybody encountered the same problem or has any ideas how to fix it or why this problem occurs?

my view looks like this:

```
@csrf_exempt 
def executeRegister(request):

if request.method == 'POST':

    data = JSONParser().parse(request)
    serializer = RegistrationSerializer(data=data)

    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()

        return JSONResponse(serializer.data, status=201)
    else:
        return JSONResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)
else:
    return HttpResponse(status=404)
```

Comment: 1. What does your RegistrationSerializer look like?  2. What's the full traceback you're seeing?

Comment: I got it fixed it didn't have anything to do with the Serializer itself though, the .save() method wanted to set an attribute which wasn't indeed set. Thx anyway